# Why I'm I getting an error when closing a file with MPI_Close

Tags: c, parallel-processing, malloc, mpi, dna-sequence

I am using MPI to open file and read from it, and do a compression to the data and rewrite it into another file so I opened two Files one in read mode and the other in write and create mode ,

```
MPI_File_open (MPI_COMM_WORLD, nom, MPI_MODE_RDONLY,
                   MPI_INFO_NULL, &myfile);
 MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,newNom,MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL,&fh);
```

and At the end I tried to close the two files because I had an error that the caracteres that I read from the file change from an execution to another

```
 if(rank==0){
        printf("Taille de fichier = %d \n",filesize);
        buf=malloc(600);
        MPI_File_read_at(myfile,0, buf, 500, MPI_CHAR, &status);

        char * endLine = strchr(buf,'\n');
        *endLine='\0';
        tailleTitre=endLine-buf;
        // posititoner le cursuer sur le premier nucleotide
        MPI_File_seek(myfile,tailleTitre+1,MPI_SEEK_SET);
        int debut=getFirstData(myfile);
        printf("Debut  = %d \n",debut);
        int fin = getLastData(myfile);
        printf("FIN  = %d \n",fin);
        total=filesize-tailleTitre-1-debut-fin;
        printf("Total de nom a lire est %d \n",total);
        int residuD = RESTANT(debut);
        int residuF = RESTANT(fin);
        printf("MET = %d \n",total-residuD-residuF);
        int net = partagerNucleotides(total-residuF-residuD,residuD,residuF,P);

        printf("Total net = %d \n",net);
        int nucleotidePerProc = diviserEnMultipleQuatre(net,P);
        int a,b;
        int a0,b0,debut0;
        // Les taches propre au master
        debut0=debut;
        debut=getOffsets(nucleotidePerProc,&a0,&b0,debut);
        printf("Proc 0 == %d == %d ,%d \n",debut0,a0,b0);
        for(int i=1;i<P;i++){
            debut=getOffsets(nucleotidePerProc,&a,&b,debut);
            //MPI_File_read_at(myfile,a,debut,b-a,MPI_CHAR,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
//            MPI_File_read(myfile,buf,b-a,MPI_CHAR,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
            MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_INTEGER,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&b,1,MPI_INTEGER,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&tailleTitre,1,MPI_INTEGER,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        buf=malloc(50);
        printf("J ai recu %d et %d  et taille = %d\n",a0,b0,tailleTitre);
        MPI_File_read_at(myfile,20,buf,b-a,MPI_CHAR,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        printf("%c\n",buf[0]);
        buf[b0-a0]='\0';
        printf("TT : %s\n",buf);
        char * test = malloc(b0-a0);
        compressData(buf,b0-a0,fh,test);
        free(test);



    }
```

This is the code i'm using to read the data from the file , It's a DNA Sequence and sometimes and get weird results , I don't know if it has a relation with the Closing of the files or no

I tried to debug to see what's the problem and here is a screenshoot 
[image]

The code is executed in a 4 cores machine with the command

```
mpirun -n 4 ./program
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: The error message suggests a memory corruption. This could be a bug in Open MPI or in your application. Can you please post a [MCVE], post your `mpirun` command line and state the filesystem you are working on?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am executing on an ubuntu Machnie with 4 cores, the command is mpirun -n 4 ./a.out

Comment: what if you `mpirun --mca io ^ompio -n 4 ./program` ?

Comment: Probably not the source of the problem, but your second call to MPI_File_read_at has an incorrect final argument - use MPI_STATUS_IGNORE (it's a single status, not an array), or better pass &status like you did the first time.